# in Circuitikz, source of error for direction to battery

Tags: circuitikz

The following code snippet produces the correct picture but also it gives an error message, namely:

undefined control sequence. ...terry1,invert, l_=\SI{12}{\ volt}] (0,4)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
to[battery1, invert, l_=\SI{33}{\ volt}] (0,4) % The voltage source
to[R=$5 \ ohms$, i=$I_1$] (4,4)
to[R=$5 \ ohms$, i>_=$I_3$] (4,0) % The resistor
to[R=$5 \ ohms$] (0,0);
\draw (8,4)
to[R, l_=$5 \ ohms$,  i_=$I_2$] (4,4);
\draw (8,4)
to[battery1,l_=\SI{10}{\ volt}] (8,0)
to[R=$5 \ ohms$] (4,0);
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{center}
```

what is my error and how do I correct it?

Comment: Probably using on `siunitx` package. Add to premable.

Comment: You have a space in `\ volt`... And in general you are using the `siunitx` package wrong. It's `\SI{12}{\volt} `, no spaces.

Comment: Please do not add answers in the body of the question. If @Zarko answer solved it, please [accept it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, that you like to draw your scheme as follows:

[image]

For writing units `circuitikz` offer `siunitx` mode, in which it adopt `siunitx` syntax `\SI{ number }{ unit }` to `number<units>`. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
to[battery1, invert, l_=33<\volt>] (0,4) % <---
to[R=5<\ohm>, i=$I_1$] (4,4) % <---
to[R=5<\ohm>, i>_=$I_3$] (4,0) % <---
to[R=5<\ohm>] (0,0); % <---
\draw (8,4)
to[R, l_=5<\ohm>, i_=$I_2$] (4,4); % <---
\draw (8,4)
to[battery1,l_=10<\volt>] (8,0) % <---
to[R=5<\ohm>] (4,0); % <---
    \end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not need to re-load `siunitx` if specified in the `circuitikz` options... ;-) otherwise it's a bug. You can load it *before* if you want to play with options.

Comment: @Rmano, you are right. Corrected (removed explicit `siunitx` loading).